# Botocore firewall ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, boto, botocore

I have a docker image running on EC2 instance that tries to issue an AWS command when I get this error

> botocore.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://ec2.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/"

If I give the EC2 instance Security Group that can access everything it works. But I look for a more limited set of rules. I already tried to give it only ports 443 and 80 (both ingress and outgress) but it doesn't work.

Any other configuration I should try?

Thanks,

Comment: "tried to give it only ports 443 and 80" - tried what? ingress, outgress rules? ACLs? Your question lacks details sadly.

Comment: Right. I gave it both: ingress and outgress rules